# Phoenix Framework Query Parameters

Tags: functional-programming, elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm attempting to build a query based on the parameters in the query string. I just started learning Elixir/OTP and functional programming, so I'm trying to find the functional way of doing this. Currently I'm reducing the map passed into the action and building a query with the found parameters. Is there a more functional or Elixir-y way of doing this?

```
query = Enum.reduce params, Event, fn(param, query) ->
  case param do
    {"after", date} ->
      date = DateTimeParser.parse!(date, "{ISO:Extended:Z}")
      from e in query,
        where: e.time > ^date
    {"before", date} ->
      date = DateTimeParser.parse!(date, "{ISO:Extended:Z}")
      from e in query,
        where: e.time < ^date
    {"eventType", type} ->
      from e in query,
        where: e.event_type_id == ^type
    _ -> query
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The only improvement I really see that can be made is using functions instead of cases, which will not matter much until you add more cases.

```
query = Enum.reduce params, Event, build_query/2

def build_query({"after", date}, query) do
  date = DateTimeParser.parse!(date, "{ISO:Extended:Z}")
  from e in query,
    where: e.time > ^date
end

# etc ...

def build_query(_, query), do: query
```

Please forgive me if I made any errors in my syntax, but I am away from home right now.  Hopefully you get the spirit of the change.